# Show that if $x(n)$ converges to $x$, then $x(n)^{1/k}$ converges to $x^{1/k}$ for all natural numbers $k$

Tags: real-analysis

I understand the case for $x(n)^{1/2}$ converges to $x^{1/2}$, but what about the more general case of $x(n)^{1/k}$?

Answer (score 1):

In a metric space such as $\mathbb{R}$ if $x_n$ is a convergent sequence and $f$ is a continuous function, then $\lim_nf(x_n)=f(\lim_nx_n)$. You just need to notice that $x\mapsto x^{1/k}$ is a continuous function for every natural $k$.

Answer (score 0):

$$L = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x(n)^\frac1k$$
$$\ln(L) = \frac1k\ln[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x(n)]$$
$$\ln(L) = \frac{\ln(x)}{k}$$
$$L = e^\frac{\ln(x)}{k}$$
$$L = x^{\frac1k}$$
Worth noting, I didn't restrict k to the natural numbers anywhere here. This should hold for all k.